# WordPress WP_Query Order doesnt work, customfield

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

Can someone help me out?

Example print_r $args:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => ketels
    [post_status] => publish
    [posts_per_page] => 6
    [orderby] => meta_value_num
    [meta_key] => prijs_met_abonnement
    [order] => ASC
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => type_woning2
                    [value] => tussenwoning
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => douche2
                    [value] => normale
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

            [prijs] => Array
                (
                    [key] => prijs_met_abonnement
                    [compare] => EXISTS
                )

        )

)
```

Posts print_r ( 'ID', 'Title', 'Price (customfield)', 'Prio (customfield)', 'MenuOrder')
Example print each posts, customfields to see where the query is filtering on:

```
ID:11090 | Title: Ne*** | Price: 1675 | Prio: 40 | Menuorder: 14
ID:11086 | Title: Va*** | Price: 1615 | Prio: 10 | Menuorder: 15
ID:11082 | Title: AT*** | Price: 1709 | Prio: 30 | Menuorder: 16
ID:11078 | Title: Re*** | Price: 1600 | Prio: 50 | Menuorder: 17
ID:11072 | Title: Ne*** | Price: 1575 | Prio: 40 | Menuorder: 18
ID:11068 | Title: AT*** | Price: 1559 | Prio: 30 | Menuorder: 19
```

Preview loop:

```
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            print_r($the_query);
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                print_r('ID:'.get_the_ID().' | '.'Title: '.get_the_title().' | Prijs: '.get_field('prijs_met_abonnement').' | Prio: '.get_field('prio').' | Menuorder: '.get_post_field('menu_order'));
            endwhile;
            die();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”? It it getting an error, no posts, the wrong posts, etc? We can’t help if we don’t know what we’re helping with!

Comment: @FluffyKitten: it is the wrong order

Comment: Doesn't order by "    [orderby] => meta_value_num
    [meta_key] => prijs_met_abonnement "

Comment: What is `prijs_met_abonnement` in relation to your post data (e.g.is it price or prio)? Do all the posts have this value? Do you get the correct order if you leave out 1 and 2 from the meta_query and use only the prijs array? Can you add this to the code before `print_r($the_query);` and edit your question to show what it includes: `echo $the_query->request;` . Its hard to know what's happening when we can't see it so you'll have to help us debug it so we can figure it out :)